# kivy & plyer Notification Error

Tags: python-2.7, notifications, kivy

I am trying to give notification in android app made in kivy as follow:

```
from plyer import notification

notification.notify('test tiltle','scanning started')
```

but i am getting this error in logcat each time

```html
chnhack/in/web_sqli/R$drawable'
I/python  (28327):  Exception in thread Thread-1:
I/python  (28327):  Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  (28327):    File "/root/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
I/python  (28327):    File "/root/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 165, in run
I/python  (28327):    File "/root/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plyer/facades/notification.py", line 21, in notify
I/python  (28327):    File "/root/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plyer/facades/notification.py", line 26, in _notify
I/python  (28327):  NotImplementedError: No usable implementation found!
I/python  (28327):  
D/dalvikvm(28327): threadid=11: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
D/dalvikvm(28327): threadid=11: thread exiting, not yet detached (count
```

It would be great if anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading this [example](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/examples/notification/main.py) and actual [code](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/plyer/platforms/android/notification.py) for notification solves your problem. `notify()` expects to pass kwargs: `icon_android`, `title`, `message`

```
notification.notify(title: 'test tiltle',message: 'scanning started')
```

For similar problems use something more real-time to ask, the best for now is the [IRC](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=kivy).

Comment: but i can not figure out how to give icon in notification...every time it takes default kivy icon

Comment: Do you use `realpath`? Just print the path until you find the correct one, because kivy takes the default one if it can't find png

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I see both `icon_android` and `app_icon` are used. I mixed them up. Use `app_icon`, because `icon_android` is from an `autoclass` from jnius.

Comment: But it still not working ... What i did is icon = "icon.png";kwargs={"message":message_variable,"title":title_variable,"app_icon":icon_variable}  this is my kwargs....and then i deploy on amdroid but it still not working

Comment: I still think the path to your icon is bad. I've been coding assets into my stuff like this `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'/icon.png'`. If even that won't help, ask on [IRC](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=kivy)